# grails3 jquery not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am newbye of grails3. Trying to use jquery basics, I got Jquery not defined in my project. Is jquery no more default for grails?
I try  at the beginning of my gsp, but giving me **not defined**. So I switch to manual refeering. 
Is it correct simply put jquery min js file in asset and use `<asset:javascript src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"/>`, or should I use another, more basic, way?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest grails as in 3.1.1 I found when it generates

> grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp

It has:

```
  <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>

    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
...

 <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
 <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
..
```

Modify this file and move that application.js under css file:

```
 </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>

    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body>
```

Try again bob may be your uncle by this point

Comment: Just moving it application.js up to the head instead of at the bottom of main.gsp worked for me.